# How to combine two strings on a report filter?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm writing VBA code for an application in Access for the first time and have created two separate strings to filter a report. The first of these strFilter filters the reports based on criteria in a list box. The second strWhere has been set up to filter the report based on a date input into a pair of text boxes. Both of these string filters work perfectly when used separately.

What I want to know is if there is a way to combine the two strings easily so that the user an filter the report based on both the criteria in the list box and the date they have entered in the text boxes.

The code I have for the listbox filter when it is added to the reports filter currently looks like this:

```
With Reports![rptFaultRecords]
    .Filter = strFilter
    .FilterOn = True
```

I want to add the string to filter by date strWhere next to the strFilter so the report can be filtered by both date and list criteria. All the code I've entered when attempting to do this has given me a run time error 3075. Is it possible for these two strings to be combined easily and if so how can I do it?

The rest of the code I've written is below if you need to see it:

```
Private Sub btnAllFaultsFilter_Click()
Dim varItem As Variant
Dim strRoom As String   
Dim strFilter As String
Dim strDevice As String
Dim strCat As String
Dim strStatus As String
Dim strDateField As String
Dim strWhere As String
Const strcJetDate = "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#"

strDateField = "[f_datereported]"

    If IsDate(Me.txtStartDate) Then
    strWhere = "(" & strDateField & " >= " & Format(Me.txtStartDate, strcJetDate) & ")"
End If
If IsDate(Me.txtEndDate) Then
    If strWhere <> vbNullString Then
        strWhere = strWhere & " AND "
    End If
    strWhere = strWhere & "(" & strDateField & " < " & Format(Me.txtEndDate + 1, strcJetDate) & ")"
End If   


For Each varItem In Me.lstRoom.ItemsSelected
    strRoom = strRoom & ",'" & Me.lstRoom.ItemData(varItem) & "'"
    Next varItem
    If Len(strRoom) = 0 Then
        strRoom = "Like '*'"
    Else
        strRoom = Right(strRoom, Len(strRoom) - 1)
        strRoom = "IN(" & strRoom & ")"
    End If
For Each varItem In Me.lstDevice.ItemsSelected
    strDevice = strDevice & ",'" & Me.lstDevice.ItemData(varItem) & "'"
    Next varItem
    If Len(strDevice) = 0 Then
        strDevice = "Like '*'"
    Else
        strDevice = Right(strDevice, Len(strDevice) - 1)
        strDevice = "IN(" & strDevice & ")"
    End If
For Each varItem In Me.lstCategory.ItemsSelected
    strCat = strCat & ",'" & Me.lstCategory.ItemData(varItem) & "'"
    Next varItem
    If Len(strCat) = 0 Then
        strCat = "Like '*'"
    Else
        strCat = Right(strCat, Len(strCat) - 1)
        strCat = "IN(" & strCat & ")"
    End If
For Each varItem In Me.lstStatus.ItemsSelected
    strStatus = strStatus & ",'" & Me.lstStatus.ItemData(varItem) & "'"
    Next varItem
    If Len(strStatus) = 0 Then
        strStatus = "Like '*'"
    Else
        strStatus = Right(strStatus, Len(strStatus) - 1)
        strStatus = "IN(" & strStatus & ")"
    End If
strFilter = "[c_roomid] " & strRoom & " AND [f_computername] " & strDevice & " AND [f_faultcategory] " & strCat & " AND [f_faultstatus] " & strStatus

With Reports![rptFaultRecords]
    '.Filter = strFilter
    .Filter = strFilter
    .FilterOn = True

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This a VBA coding issue and not a dba one. If you have, for example, an SQL query that you have a problem with, get back to us. Take the tour, visit the Help Centre and check out the "help us to help you" blog. I'm going to have to vote to close unless this question can be made on-topic (doubtful) - it belongs on StackOverflow.